# Automate pagination and save DOM HTML (content table) of each page for an authenticated website

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, pagination, browser-automation

First, I am not a very technical person, but a business user. I have logged into an authenticated industry database (of which I have official access to). Post logging in, I can see a paginated list of all companies in whichever industry I want to. I need to download the list programmatically, as it will be highly time consuming to go thru each resulting page.

The 1st page URL for any particular industry looks like:

http : // < Website name > / companies.html ? indId = < xyz >

where <> contains relevant info.

1st problem:
Even if I keep pagination (2nd problem) aside, I cannot save page to get data. I need its browser DOM (HTML for view-source is different). I want to do this programmatically. How do I do it?

2nd problem:
The URL for page 2, 3, and so on (pagination) shows me a different URL being called from one on the browser (which does not change). I know the structure of that URL, but copy pasting that URL results in an error page (instead of data), because the server expects only POST. Please see eg below:

http :// < Website name > / companyList.html ? perPage = 25 & page = 2

Thus, I cannot even create a script for subsequent pages that can generate data for those pages. I have all the required header / cookie / and form data with me.

Please suggest how to solve both the problems. Essentially, it is a complex browser automation problem. I have evaluated a number of automation tools / scripts, but none seem to be of exact help.

Many Thanks.

Comment: for #1, use tampermonkey to invoke downloadify to save document.documentElement.outerHTML to a file for each page. 2. you can use JS to click() the same links that bring the page up for a human, and tampermonkey will automatically re-kick-in when the new page loads.

Comment: @dandavis thanks. i have installed tampermonkey on my chrome. can you please provide a link to the downloadify script you are referring to? also, for 2. can you please explain how do i click()?

Comment: basically my workflow is: 1. i know how many pages exist. 2. i can see content of 1st page. 3. i need to download Browser DOM Table element. 4. i click on next page. 5. i download Browser DOM Table for that page. 6. i repeat 4 and 5 till all my pages are over.<br/><br/> many thanks again.

Comment: you can use my downloader instead at http://danml.com/js/download.js. pasting that code into your user script, you would call download(document.documentElement.outerHTML, document.title+".html", "text/html") to save the page upon load. you then have to find the right button and click it, which is a bit tricky unless the button has an id attrib. if it does, say <button id=next>, then just call setTimeout('next.click()', 1000) right under the download call. if not, you need to use document.querySelector(css) to find the button, and if present, call .click() on it

Comment: hi @dandavis. many thanks & sorry for getting back late. when i use tampermonkey to execute even a simple script it gives me the following error: 
env: execute script DanMLDownload @ the pseudo-safe context now! VM105:56
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
and all i am doing is run a simple script not even the full download script that you provided. the script goes as: 
$(function(){
window.alert("Hello.. My Extension processed you..");
});
Please help.

Comment: sadly, i have no clue what that message means, and userscripts are hard to help someone else get running. you should cut the code out of the file on my site (it's only a couple kb) and paste it into your userscript (something.user.js). you should not need to load any files to use the script, so a 403 shouldn't happen...

Comment: thanks @dandavis. sorry, i am a newbie, and had initially thought the server response (forbidden) was for this script, but in reality it was for one of the links within the website itself, which i later realized. yes, i was able to execute the script but was unable to fetch the data. i still get view-source. it in no way allows me to fetch DOM. your responses till now have been very helpful. thanks again. what details would you need from my side to explain the situation better? i have also sent you an email...

Comment: <div class="loading"><img src="http://<Website name>/cdn/release_36_0_0_0/images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." /> Loading...</div><div id="companyListResults" class="innerHtmlResults"></div>

Above is what I get. The companyListResults div is not empty in Inspect Element.